# Is there always a difference between /ə(ɹ)z/ and /ɪz/?

Tags: pronunciation, weak-vowel-merger

Is there always a difference between the following two sounds:

- /ɪz/ as in the end of 'hedges'
- /ə(ɹ)z/ as in the end of 'ledgers'

They seem super close. Is there any accent in which they sound the same, perhaps because of vowel reduction?

Comment: If there is such an accent, speakers would need to handle pairs like *ledges/ledgers*

Comment: Is that unheard of? Seems to me that lazily saying the former ends up as the latter

Comment: (perhaps you've already thought this far ahead, but:) In a non rhotic accent you'd lose the "r".  In RP British English they are pretty close, but definitely differentiated. My first guess would be probably most scouse dialects would have ledges and ledgers as homophones? But it might just be that they're closer rather than merged

Comment: I would guess that even in non-rhotic accents the person steeped in the accent would be able to hear a slight difference, though folks more attuned to rhotic accents might be confused.

Comment: [Strongly related and possible duplicates](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=weak+vowel+merger).